# Microsoft Flow - REST API not supported

Tags: sharepoint-online, workflow, sharepoint-rest-api, microsoft-flow

I am testing the microsoft flow and trying to create a workflow where the trigger is when an email is being received. I'm using office 365 outlook. However, the system states that there is a **invalid connection** and with

error message:

> **Please check your account info and/or permissions and try again. Details: REST API is not yet supported for this mailbox. clientRequestId:xxxxxxxxxx**

I look through the microsoft documentation [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/api/mail-rest-operations) and [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/api/use-outlook-rest-api#azure-ad-v2-authentication-endpoint) but seems like its more for applications, but I'm just creating a workflow and plan to use on sharepoint online, do I have to gone through all that?

I'm using Office 365 Enterprise E3, Microsoft Flow is being included. I also look through other articles, some mention that user might need to migrated to Office 365. I'm already using office 365 outlook.

[image]

Or am I just looking at the wrong articles? This is my first time creating a workflow, appreciate if could provide me some articles to read and understand what's going on. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you check this https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Flows/REST-API-is-not-yet-supported-for-this-mailbox/td-p/3452

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a problem with your mailbox. Either it's not a valid Office 365 mailbox it it does not have the appropriate license.

Comment: Hi may I know what do you mean by not validated mailbox? I’m currently using the same email to receive and sent email to others. In term of license, it states that I’m using the free plan, do I need another license when it already states that I’m using the free plan?

Comment: Just confirmed. For those who uses free plan. You will need a license in order to create. [Check here for more information](https://emea.flow.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/). Sadly for my case, my IT department does not support microsoft flow so I can't use it